# Sort By date Not working with Bootstrap 4 Datatables

Tags: datatables

I have a table that pulls in data from a MySQL database. The dates are in this format: YYYY-MM-DD. I am using Bootstrap 4 Datatables to display the table. Everything works but, the dates never sort correctly. I want to display the dates as mm/dd/yyyy format.  I can get it to sort correctly if the date is in this format: yyyy-mm-dd but, I want to display and sort it in this format: dmm/dd/yyyy.

Here is my code:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style type="text/css">
td img {margin: 0;}
table.sortable th:not(.sorttable_sorted):not(.sorttable_sorted_reverse):not(.sorttable_nosort):after { 
    content: " \25B4\25BE" 
}
table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td {
  background: #cccccc;
}
table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) td {
  background: #ccfffff;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
    "order": [0, 'desc']
} );
} );
    </script>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" id="example" cellpadding="5" class="display table-striped table-responsive">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>
          <th>End Time</th>
          <th>Location</th>
          <th>Purpose</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
while(!$meetings->atEnd()) {
?>
        <tr> 
        <td><?php echo($meetings->getColumnVal("title"));  ?></td>  
          <td><?php echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($meetings->getColumnVal("meeting_date"))); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo date("h:i a", strtotime($meetings->getColumnVal("start_time"))); ?></td>  
          <td><?php echo date("h:i a", strtotime($meetings->getColumnVal("end_time"))); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo($meetings->getColumnVal("thelocation2")); ?></td>
           <td><?php echo($meetings->getColumnVal("topic")); ?></td>
          <td><?php /*START_PHP_SIRFCIT*/ if ($meetings->getColumnVal("cancelled") == NULL and $meetings->getColumnVal("revised") == NULL) { ?><a href="view_notice.php?meetingID=<?php echo($meetings->getColumnVal("theID")); ?>" title="Notice" target="_blank">Notice (pdf)</a><?php } ?><?php /*START_PHP_SIRFCIT*/ if ($meetings->getColumnVal("revised") == 'Y') { ?><a href="view_notice_revised.php?meetingID=<?php echo($meetings->getColumnVal("theID")); ?>" title="Notice" target="_blank">Notice (pdf)</a><?php } ?><?php /*START_PHP_SIRFCIT*/ if ($meetings->getColumnVal("cancelled") == 'Y') { ?><a href="view_notice_cancelled.php?meetingID=<?php echo($meetings->getColumnVal("theID")); ?>" title="Notice" target="_blank">Notice (pdf)</a><?php } ?><?php /*START_PHP_SIRFCIT*/ if ($meetings->getColumnVal("agendaID") != NULL) { ?><br><a href="view_agenda.php?meetingID=<?php echo($meetings->getColumnVal("theID")); ?>" title="Agenda">Agenda</a><?php } ?><?php /*START_PHP_SIRFCIT*/ if ($meetings->getColumnVal("minutes_file") != NULL) { ?><br><a href="admin/minutes/<?php echo($meetings->getColumnVal("minutes_file")); ?>" title="Minutes" target="_blank">Minutes</a><?php } ?><?php /*START_PHP_SIRFCIT*/ if ($meetings->getColumnVal("video_url") != NULL) { ?><br><a href="<?php echo($meetings->getColumnVal("video_url")); ?>" target="_blank" title="Watch Video">Video</a><?php } ?><?php /*START_PHP_SIRFCIT*/ if ($meetings->getColumnVal("presentation_url") != NULL) { ?><br><a href="<?php echo($meetings->getColumnVal("presentation_url")); ?>" target="_blank" title="Watch Presentation">Presentation</a><?php } ?><?php if(time() <= strtotime("-30 minutes", strtotime( $meetings->getColumnVal("meeting_date")." ".$meetings->getColumnVal("start_time")  ))){ ?>
<br><a href="register.php?meetingID=<?php echo($meetings->getColumnVal("theID")); ?>" title="register">Register to Attend</a><?php }?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
  $meetings->moveNext();
}
$meetings->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record
?>
      </tbody></table>
```

Comment: One approach: [Orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) lets you display data using one format but sort it (and filter it) using a different format. There are various examples in different SO questions, as well as the examples in the provided link.

Comment: To help with converting between date formats, the [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/) library is very useful. Here, too, there are various SO questions which should provide examples.

Comment: I have been trying to use moment.js but, can't seem to figure it out. It always fails.

Comment: Assuming you have added the library correctly, an example using moment:  `var displayDate = '03/15/2021';` followed by `var sortDate = moment(displayDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');`. The sortDate is a string containing `2021-03-15`. This further assumes that all your input dates consistently match the provided pattern of MM/DD/YYYY. The logic is: input string -> moment object -> output string.

Comment: (Side note: I notice that there are more modern alternatives to moment.js - even ones that the Moment team [recommends themselves](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/).)